# Integration testing DelegatingHandlers of a HttpClient instance

Tags: .net, rest, integration-testing, dotnet-httpclient

I have a wrapper around HttpClientFactory that wires up a default DelegatingHandler to HttpClient via HttpClientFactory.Create. It's adds some headers.. etc to the outgoing request. I need to make sure that my handlers are always the last to run before the actual request is made. This is the gist of my factory method.

```
    public static HttpClient Create(params DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
    {
        var handlerList = handlers.ToList();
        handlerList.Add(new ModuleClientHandler());
        return HttpClientFactory.Create(handlerList.ToArray());
    }
```

It's works, but I'd like to write some tests around my expectations. How can I do this with HttpServer with an existing instance of HttpClient?

Passing HttpServer into the handlers list won't work since it would get wired up before my ModuleClientHandler handler and return a HttpResponse before the handler runs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
public static class HandlerHelper
{
    public static HttpClientHandler Server;
    public static HttpClient Create(params DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
    {
        var handlerList = handlers.ToList();
        handlerList.Add(new ModuleClientHandler());
        if (Server == null)
        {
            return HttpClientFactory.Create(handlerList.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            return HttpClientFactory.Create(Server, handlerList.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Just assign your `HttpServer` instance to the `Server` property, and you can then test.